# JavaFX TableCell vs Swing TableCellRenderer instances

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

This is my issue, I have a table that has 50 columns and 10000 rows and all the data are strings.  In Swing when I have one TableCellRenderer that renders the strings for the whole table.

In JavaFx to render the same table I have 50000 TableCell objects created.

Did I missing something here?  This will never have any performance, to allocate 50K of object is not acceptable.

Is there a way in JavaFx to use just one TableCell to render all my cells and have a similar behavior to Swing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Javadoc for the Cell class:

> Because TreeView, ListView, TableView and other such controls can potentially be used for displaying incredibly large amounts of data, it is not feasible to create an actual Cell for every single item in the control. We represent extremely large data sets using only very few Cells. Each Cell is "recycled", or reused. This is what we mean when we say that these controls are virtualized.

Basically, a TableView will only create as many cell instances as it needs to render the content visible on screen. If you scroll the table, cells get recycled. Basically, this should give you the same performance as with Swing, trading a small memory overhead for an easier programming model.

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much.  I actually feel silly.  I read the JavaDoc on Cell but this crucial point did not hit me until you posted it! Thanks.